# Eleventy server ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: server, terminal, static-site, npx, eleventy

I'm successfully running Jekyll and Gatsby sites, but when I tried Eleventy, I had a problem. When I do the Quickstart process described at `https://www.11ty.dev/docs/getting-started/`, it successfully gives me this output:

```
$ npx @11ty/eleventy --serve --port=8000
Writing _site/README/index.html from ./README.md.
Writing _site/index.html from ./index.html.
Wrote 2 files in 0.15 seconds (v0.11.1)
Watching…
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:8000
    External: http://192.168.7.233:8000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: _site
```

However, when I navigate to any of the access URLs listed here, the browser tab just spins for a few minutes, then says "This page isn't working. localhost didn't send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

I opened both of the files that were written, and confirmed they are correct.

```
//_site/index.html
<!doctype html><html><head><title>Page title</title></head><body><p>Hi</p></body></html>
```

```
//_site/README/index.html
<!doctype html><html><head><title>Page title</title></head><body><p>Hi</p></body></html>
```

I've tried Chrome and Firefox.

I've tried changing the port with `npx @11ty/eleventy --serve --port=8081` and navigating to port 8081, and several other ports.

I've tried all of this on a 2019 MacBook Pro and a 2013 MacBook Pro, both using iTerm2, and got the same results.

---

More information. I tried the quickstart instructions for another static site framework which I never tried before: Wintersmith. The same thing happens when I go to the browser to preview the resulting site on localhost. The browser tab just spins until it gets an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Then I went back to one of my existing Jekyll sites, just in case it also got an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on localhost. However, when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` it shows up in the browser just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. The firewall in my ESET virus protection software, on both of my MacBooks, was blocking connections which bind to the unspecified ipv6 address on the double-colon. `::` Eleventy and Wintersmith do that. Jekyll and Gatsby do not.

https://forum.eset.com/topic/22080-mac-firewall-issue-after-update-to-684000/

As soon as I turned off my ESET firewall protection, I could see my Eleventy and Wintersmith sites in the browser.